# Array 'result' is ['o'] before return. After the return, it's [ ]. How?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, tree

I have this Tree exercise to return the next letter to suggest typing for a simplified search bar feature, where I have to implement the `WordTree.prototype.search` function. Here's the basic functionality:

```
tree.search('Levi'); // returns [] (adds each letter) 
tree.search('Lego'); // returns []
tree.search('Le'); // returns ['g', 'v'], suggesting 'g' and 'v' from the previous entries
tree.search('Leg'); // ['o'], suggesting 'o' from 'Lego'
```

The resulting tree should be (verified with a console.log):

```
* * (root)
  |
  -- L
     |
     -- e
        |
        -- v
        |  |
        |  -- e
        |  |  |
        |  |  -- l
        |  |
        |  -- i
        |
        -- g
           |
           -- o
```

Here is my code. The last line contains the test, which doesn't work, *but should*. I also marked with `*******` in the code to show where the `result` is equal to `['o']` but when returned to either the `chai.expect` test or the console.log, it's `[]`. **How can this happen?**

```
var expect = require('chai').expect;

var Node = function(data) {
  this.data = data;
  this.children = [];
};

var WordTree = function() {
  var node = new Node({});
  this.root = node;
};

WordTree.prototype.search = function(word, nodes) {
// code starts here
  var currentLetter = word.charAt(0);

  if (nodes === undefined) { // if top-level search...
    if( !containsLetter(this.root.children, currentLetter) ) {
      var newLetter = new Node(currentLetter);
      this.root.children.push(newLetter);
      this.search(word); // add the rest of the word
      return [];
    } else { // first letter exists, so let's begin search recursively
      var nodeIndex = getNodeIndexWithLetter(this.root.children, currentLetter);
      return this.search(word.slice(1), this.root.children[nodeIndex].children );
    }
  } else { // if 'nodes' is defined, we know recursion is going on

    // if last letter in 'word', suggest the next possible words in the tree
    if( word.length === 1 ){
      var result = [];
        if(containsLetter(nodes, currentLetter) ) {
          var currLetterChildren = nodes[ getNodeIndexWithLetter(nodes, currentLetter) ].children;
          result = currLetterChildren.map(function getChildrenData(childNode) {
            return childNode.data;
          });
          // console.log(result); // <--- *****THIS IS ['o'] ****
          return result;  // <---- BUT IT RETURNS [].
        } else {
          nodes.push(new Node(currentLetter))
        }
        return result;
      }

      // if there are more letters to traverse...
      if( !containsLetter(nodes, currentLetter) ) {
        var newLetter = new Node(currentLetter);
        nodes.push(newLetter);
        this.search(word.slice(1), newLetter.children); // add the rest of the word
        } else {
          this.search(word.slice(1), nodes[ getNodeIndexWithLetter(nodes, currentLetter)].children);
        }
      }
      return [];

      // these are O(n). Something to fix later
      function containsLetter(childArray, num){
        var found = false;
        childArray.forEach(function(child) {
        if(child.data === num)
          found = true;
        })
        return found;
      }
      // O(n). Fix later.
      function getNodeIndexWithLetter(nodeArray, num) {
        var index = -1;
        nodeArray.forEach(function(element, i) {
          if(element.data === num)
            index = i;
        })
        return index;
      }
    };

  var tree = new WordTree();

  expect(tree.search('Levi')).to.deep.equal([]);
  expect(tree.search('Level')).to.deep.equal([]);
  expect(tree.search('Lego')).to.deep.equal([]);
  expect(tree.search('Le')).to.deep.equal(['v', 'g']);
  console.log(
    tree.search('Leg')
  );
  // console.log(JSON.stringify(tree.root));
  // expect(tree.search('Leg')).to.deep.equal(['o']); // <-- something is off about this test
```

Comment: Use a debugger and narrow down the problem

Comment: Good suggestion. Looking into debuggers, I discovered I have too many 'result =' statements, but I still don't understand why the return statement doesn't just break out of the callstack.

Answer (score 0):

This is the corrected version. Basically, I learned to **debug Node.js programs with `node debug filename.js`**. The issue was that **the recursive/nested return statements were broken and the `search` function continued going in the outer calls, to a point where the result was an empty array `[]`**

```js
var expect = require('chai').expect;

var Node = function(data) {
  this.data = data;
  this.parent = null;
  this.children = [];
};

var WordTree = function() {
  var node = new Node({});
  this.root = node;
};

WordTree.prototype.search = function(word, nodes) {
  // your code goes here
  var currentLetter = word.charAt(0);

  if (nodes === undefined) { // if top-level search...
    if (!containsLetter(this.root.children, currentLetter)) { // if new word...
      var newLetter = new Node(currentLetter);
      this.root.children.push(newLetter);
      this.search(word); // ... add the rest of the word...
      return []; // ... and return nothing
    } else { // first letter exists, so let's begin search recursively
      var nodeIndex = getNodeIndexWithLetter(this.root.children, currentLetter);
      return this.search(word.slice(1), this.root.children[nodeIndex].children);
    }

  } else { // if 'nodes' is defined, we know recursion is going on

    // if we're in the last letter in 'word', suggest the next possible letters in the tree, if any
    if (word.length === 1) {
      if (containsLetter(nodes, currentLetter)) {
        var currLetterChildren = nodes[getNodeIndexWithLetter(nodes, currentLetter)].children;
        var result = currLetterChildren.map(function getChildrenData(childNode) {
          return childNode.data;
        });
        return result;

      } else { // ... otherwise the last letter doesn't exist. Add it and return nothing
        nodes.push(new Node(currentLetter))
        return [];
      }
    }

    // if there are still multiple letters to traverse...
    if (!containsLetter(nodes, currentLetter)) { // ... and a letter was not found...
      var newLetter = new Node(currentLetter);
      nodes.push(newLetter);
      this.search(word.slice(1), newLetter.children); // ... add the rest of the word...
      return []; // return nothing because a new letter in the tree means new word
    } else { // ... if a letter was found we might possibly return something...
      return this.search(word.slice(1), nodes[getNodeIndexWithLetter(nodes, currentLetter)].children);
    }
  }

  // ** Utility functions below **
  // These are defined in the search function because they pertain to this function only
  // No need to litter the global scope with utility functions

  // These are O(n). Possibly something to fix later
  function containsLetter(childArray, num) {
      var found = false;
      childArray.forEach(function(child) {
        if (child.data === num)
          found = true;
      })
      return found;
    }
    // O(n). Fix later.

  function getNodeIndexWithLetter(nodeArray, num) {
    var index = -1;
    nodeArray.forEach(function(element, i) {
      if (element.data === num)
        index = i;
    })
    return index;
  }
};

var tree = new WordTree();

expect(tree.search('Levi')).to.deep.equal([]);
expect(tree.search('Level')).to.deep.equal([]);
expect(tree.search('Lego')).to.deep.equal([]);
expect(tree.search('Le')).to.deep.equal(['v', 'g']);
expect(tree.search('Leg')).to.deep.equal(['o']);
```